# How do i make a game director in python?

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to make a game director in python, but failing miserably as when i try to open the second program, it does in the order, so first 1, then 2, etc here is a part of my code:

```
*import os
print('What game do you want to play?')
print('1.  Hangman')
print('2.  Dragon Realm')
print('3.  Crafting Challenge')
gamechoice = input()
if gamechoice == '1':
    print('Ok, sending you there...')
os.startfile('hangman.py')
gamechoice = input()
if gamechoice == '2':
    print('Ok, sending you there...')
os.startfile('Dragon Realm.py')
gamechoice = input()
if gamechoice == '3':
    print('Ok, sending you there...')
os.startfile('crafting challenge.py')*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to get the input once. And in the if-statements you need to indent properly so you don't execute code that you didn't mean too.

Something like this might work:

```
import os
print('What game do you want to play?')
print('1.  Hangman')
print('2.  Dragon Realm')
print('3.  Crafting Challenge')

gamechoice = input()
print('Ok, sending you there...')

if gamechoice == 1:
    os.startfile('hangman.py')
elif gamechoice == 2:
    os.startfile('Dragon Realm.py')
elif gamechoice == 3:
    os.startfile('crafting challenge.py')
```